# Understanding an element of the main loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm just starting out with Python. And I need help understanding how to do the main loop of my program.

I have a source file with two columns of data, temperature & time. This file gets updated every 60 seconds by a bash script.

I successfully wrote these three separate programs;
1. A program that can read the last 1440 lines of the source data and plot out a day graph.
2. A program that can read the last 10080 lines of the source data and plot out a week graph.
3. A program that can read the source data and just display the last recorded temperature.
4. Check the size of the source file and delete data over X days old.

I want to put it all together so that a user can toggle between the 3 different display types. I understand that this would work in a main loop, with just have the input checked in the loop, and call a function based on what is returned.

But I don't know how to handle the file size check. I don't want it checked every time the loops cycles.  I would like it to be run once a day.

thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried?  Can you add a brief example of what you are doing/ what you want?

Comment: What type of user interface does your program have? If you're using a GUI toolkit of any type, there's likely to be a way to schedule something to happen in the future (the once-per-day file recheck) and also respond to user input whenever it happens. However, different libraries work very differently, so there may not be a generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a variable outside of the loop which stores the last time the data size was checked.  Every time through your loop you can compare the current time vs the last time every time through the loop and check if more than X time has elapsed.